# MySQL & PHP: querying 3 rows at a time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm working on a photo gallery using a database. On each line 3 images are displayed before everything resets. It would be in a `<img>/<img>/<img>/<div>` format.

So when looking at the source code you'd have:

```
<img src="1" alt="">
<img src="2" alt="">
<img src="3" alt="">
<div class="clear-both"></div>
```

And it would keep repeating this for every row in the data base. So 9 images would be:

```
<img src="1" alt="">
<img src="2" alt="">
<img src="3" alt="">
<div class="clear-both"></div>
<img src="4" alt="">
<img src="5" alt="">
<img src="6" alt="">
<div class="clear-both"></div>
<img src="7" alt="">
<img src="8" alt="">
<img src="9" alt="">
<div class="clear-both"></div>
```

I figured I could use `while` to handle this. But I don't know what SQL or PHP statement to add. I thought about using `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`, but none of these work.

If possible, I also want it to be able to handle rows with just 1 and 2 images. Meaning if there are 4 rows in the table, then it would display:

```
<img src="1" alt="">
<img src="2" alt="">
<img src="3" alt="">
<div class="clear-both"></div>
<img src="4" alt="">
<div class="clear-both"></div>
```

And if there were 8, then it would display:

```
<img src="1" alt="">
<img src="2" alt="">
<img src="3" alt="">
<div class="clear-both"></div>
<img src="4" alt="">
<img src="5" alt="">
<img src="6" alt="">
<div class="clear-both"></div>
<img src="7" alt="">
<img src="8" alt="">
<div class="clear-both"></div>
```

Thanks for the help.

## PHP

```
$Database4 = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "Photography");
$Photos = $Database4 -> query("SELECT *
                               FROM `Year2016`
                               -- ORDER BY DateTaken
                               ;");

while ($DataRows = $Photos -> fetch_array()) {
 echo '<img src="photography/small/' . $DataRows["file"] . '" alt="">' . "\n";
}

echo '<div class="clear-both"></div>' . "\n";
```

## SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `Year2016`(
 `file` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_bin;

INSERT INTO `Year2016`(`file`)
VALUES
('red-1.png'),
('red-2.png'),
('red-3.png'),
('red-4.png'),
('red-5.png'),
('red-6.png');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy as a pie:

```
$i = 1;    // special counter
while ($DataRows = $Photos -> fetch_array()) {
    echo '<img src="photography/small/' . $DataRows["file"] . '" alt="">' . "\n";
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo '<div class="clear-both"></div>';
    }
    $i++;
}
// the last one if last `$i` value is not divided by 3
if ($i % 3 != 1) {
    echo '<div class="clear-both"></div>';
}
```